# Библиотека JasPer для работы с *.jp2

Tags: c++, изображения, библиотеки

Для работы с форматом jpeg2000 порекомендовали библиотеку JasPer (http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~frodo/jasper/), однако примеров её использования я найти не смог. Возможно, кто-нибудь знает, как с помощью этой библиотеки создать хотя бы простенькие изображения - квадрат n*n какого-нибудь цвета или подобные?

Comment: Джаспер это кодек, он нужен чтобы сжимать/рахжимать изображения. А вы с помощью него собрались создавать изображения. Где логика? Или поясните вопрос, пример чего вам нужен?

Comment: Там с ним идет утилита, которая и называется собственно jasper. Посмотрте ее исходники - ничего сложного.

Comment: @Cerbo, дело в том, что нужно разобраться, что в этом кодеке отвечает за DWT, что за квантование и что за арифметическое кодирование. Планируется модифицировать изображения на этапе между квантованием и кодированием. Т.к в коде я этого явно не нашел, думал посмотреть в процессе работы кодека. Именно для этого было нужно посмотреть "процесс создания изображения".

Comment: ну тогда посмотрите еще http://www.openjpeg.org/

Answer (score 1):

Примеры использования библиотеки, вероятно, можно посмотреть, например, в исходных текстах программ, эту библиотеку использующих.

Вот, к примеру, список пакетов, у которых в зависимостях стоит пакет `libjasper1`:

```
aaphoto
ayttm
dcraw
digikam-private-libs
edisplay
exactimage
flextra
gimp
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
kdelibs5-plugins
kopete
libexactimage-perl
libgdal1h
libgdal-perl
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
libgegl-0.2-0
libgraphicsmagick3
libgraphics-magick-perl
libgrib2c0d
libgrib-api-1.10.4
libgrib-api-tools
libgs9
libicns1
libjasper1
libjasper-dev
libjasper-runtime
libmagickcore5
libopencv-highgui2.4
libopenscenegraph100
libraw10
metview
ncl-ncarg
php5-exactimage
python-exactimage
qsstv
qt5-image-formats-plugins
saga
xastir
xbmc-bin
ziproxy
```

Получить информацию о пакете, не имея под рукой установленного дистрибутива `debian gnu/linux`, можно, например по ссылке `https://packages.debian.org/jessie/name`, где `name` — имя пакета. на открывшейся странице с правой стороны будет список ссылок, относящихся к пакету. Там будет и ссылка на исходные тексты (примерного вида *название_пакета-версия-orig.tar.gz*).

Comment: Пробовал делать по аналогии с библиотекой OpenCV, где работа с jpeg2000 ведется посредством JasPer, но кроме пустого файла ничего создать не удалось.